# Summary on async (void) Method: What to return?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, async-await

This is maybe a trivial question but currently im doing some Inline-Documentation for future Coworkers and stumbled upon something like that:

```
/// <summary>
/// This Class is totaly useless
/// </summary>
public class DummyClass {

  /// <summary>
  /// Will do nothing
  /// </summary>
  public void DoNothing() {
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Will do nothing async
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns></returns> <---- What to write here?
  public async Task DoNothingAsync() {
    await Task.Run(() => { });
  }

}
```

As you might know, typing 3 slashes above an Method/Field/Class/whatever, triggers VisualStudio to perform its Summary-Snippet-Completion.

**Question**

Is `Task` actually a valid return-value? And if so, what do i write in the `<returns></returns>`?

I surely do know, i can ignore this, but for the sake of completeness im willing to write stuff there.

Comment: Either nothing, or an empty task. I'd be tempted to leave it as a blank `returns` tag, as documentation isn't there to teach people about programming (so I'd advise against saying something like 'an awaitable task' - that is clear to a developer who understands async in c#), but to describe your method - which returns nothing.

Comment: Just FYI, that `DoNothingAsync` will actually spawn a thread to do nothing, so I’d argue that it would not do nothing ;P A better way to do nothing would be to return e.g. `Task.FromResult(0)`. (I know it’s just for demonstration purposes)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If we take inspiration from [API's that Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227200.aspx) have produced recently, you might just state:

```xml
<returns>No object or value is returned by this method when it completes.</returns>
```

I dislike "A task object that can be awaited" for the same reason I wouldn't decorate a method that returns an `int` with "an integer which can be compared to zero or used in mathematical operations" - it doesn't describe the return value of the method, it describes the type. The type has its own documentation which can be consulted.

Answer (score 12):

Personally, I do prefer to remove that `<returns></returns>` part in this case.

When you return a `Task`, you're actually returning an object that allows the caller to know when the method ends (In various ways, one of which is to `await` it). You're not actually returning any result from the method (The way you do when you return a `Task<T>`),so you're just returning a way of communication with the caller.

If you had to write something, i prefer something that is helpful to whomever is using the API:

```
/// <returns>A task object that can be awaited</returns>
```

Comment: I would also remove it. The documented <return></return> is meant for sharing information about what the function returns, not how C# works. it would be the same as writing "a positive or negative numerical value" if you returned `int`, and I'm sure that feels unecessary :)

Comment: Hahaha that's amazing, I just realized Damien used the **exact same** example as me !

Comment: @Zil Documentation is meant to be useful to whomever is using the API. I find this line as useful in case the author needs to write something. Else I still prefer to remove that part. Things like, *Nothing is returned from this method* is really confusing in case you wrote `Task t = DoNothingAsync()`

Comment: @GilSand I just wish generating XML documentation wouldn't create warnings in case of not documenting a `cancellationToken` parameter or `(Value)Task` return. Made me disable all of its warnings for "missing documentation".

Answer (score 3):

> Is Task actually a valid return-value?

Absolutely. This is what the async-state machine relies on under-the-covers. Semantically speaking, there is always a lot of confusion around having a return type defined without a corresponding `return` statement within the method body. This method could be written as such instead:

```
public Task DoNothingAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => { });
}
```

> What do I write in the `<returns></returns>`?

When I utilize the `<summary></summary>` documentation features, I usually do not populate the `<return></return>` as **IntelliSense** will tell you the type already. Additionally, it will tell you if it is an "(awaitable)" which is really the key here anyways. If you're writing a method that returns a `Task` for example, it is awaitable and that is really the most important part.

If you feel obligated to describe it, I would suggest doing so as such:

```
<returns>
   A <see cref="Task"> object that represents an asynchronous operation.
</returns>
```

Again, the IDE will let you know when you're consuming this function that it is "awaitable".

[image]

**Note:**

**[AsyncFixer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/03448836-db42-46b3-a5c7-5fc5d36a8308)** is an extension that will highlight suggestions for you, such as telling you that these should actually be `return` statements instead and that the `async` and `await` keywords are not needed.

Answer (score 2):

As from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Each returned task represents ongoing work. A task encapsulates
>   information about the state of the asynchronous process and,
>   eventually, either the final result from the process or the exception
>   that the process raises if it doesn't succeed.

So you can write your method returns a piece of work (= a task, which I´d argue *is* a valid return-type) that when executed returns nothing (`void`) in your case.

Answer (score 2):

If simplify - this return like `void` , so you can even write **awaitable void** is return.

But if be serious of course return **Task** is actually a valid return-value.

Answer (score 0):

Following the Microsoft docs of other methods. We have always something like:

- `Asynchronously does something...`
- `A <task> that represents the asynchronous ...`

You can see examples such as:

- [Stream.CopyToAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync?view=netframework-4.8)
- [ChannelReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readasync?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Channels_ChannelReader_1_ReadAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)